# solve hcaptcha without form or return function

Tags: 2captcha

someone knows how to solve hcaptcha without challenger-form, normally one would make a submit to the form but in this case it does not contain and I cannot find what the callback function would be

the is the web: https://size.ca/pages/raffle?t=1621794388843

[image]